# How to use Primefaces Callback in Backing Bean?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

I am developing a web page with HTML5 canvas, it will be presented in real-time dashboards, for that i used ManagedBean to return their values​​, my page have a component developed in JavaScript with its variable declared as global, and every 3 seconds should be updated its values , ​through of the `pool` of Primefaces, but it does not happen, the code is executed only once after the page rendering, as can be seen in the generated code below by the primefaces:

```
<script id="j_idt2:j_idt3_s" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw("Poll", "widget_j_idt2_j_idt3", {
            id: "j_idt2:j_idt3",
            widgetVar: "widget_j_idt2_j_idt3",
            frequency: 2,
            autoStart: true,
            fn: function() {
                PrimeFaces.ab({
                    s: 'j_idt2:j_idt3',
                    f: 'j_idt2',
                    u: 'j_idt2',
                    d: 3,
                    onco: function(xhr, status, args) {
                        radial1.setValueAnimated(36.16220080628247);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I set the value of my object by calling a JavaScript method with a time interval in JavaScript by a method of ManageBean?

```
<body onload="init()">
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />

    <h:form>
        <p:poll oncomplete  =   "radial1.setValueAnimated(#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste})" listener="#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}" 
                autoStart   =   "true"
                delay       =   "3"
                update      =   "@form"
        />              

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                    <canvas id="canvasRadial1" width="200" height="200">
                        No canvas in your browser...sorry...
                    </canvas>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </h:form>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

     var radial1;

    function init()
    {
        // Define some sections
        var sections = Array(steelseries.Section(0, 25, 'rgba(0, 0, 220, 0.3)'),
                             steelseries.Section(25, 50, 'rgba(0, 220, 0, 0.3)'),
                             steelseries.Section(50, 75, 'rgba(220, 220, 0, 0.3)'));

        // Define one area
        var areas = Array(steelseries.Section(75, 100, 'rgba(220, 0, 0, 0.3)'));


        // Initialzing gauge
        radial1 = new steelseries.Radial('canvasRadial1', {
                                         gaugeType: steelseries.GaugeType.TYPE1,
                                         section: sections,
                                         area: areas,
                                         titleString: 'Title',
                                         unitString: 'Unit',
                                         threshold: 50,
                                         lcdVisible: true
                            });

        // O método abaixo deve ser executado eternamente, como sugerido usando pool, mas o fato de estar em uma função JavaScript
        // aparentemente não é possível
        gauge.setValueAnimated(#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste});
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Uses Primefaces `p:poll` primefaces or `p:remoteCommand` to invoke a  Backing Bean `action`.

   ```
   <p:poll autoStart="true" listener="#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}"
           oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" interval="3" />
   ```

   Or with the `p:remoteCommand`:

   ```
   <p:remoteCommand name="atualizarUI" actionListener="#{mBeanTesteIsolado.teste}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
   ```

   In case of `p:remoteCommand`, using a setInterval to call with time:

   ```
   setInterval(function() { atualizarUI(); }, 3000);
   ```
2. In Backing Bean, uses the `RequestContext.addCallbackParam` to return values to JavaScript fuction used in `oncomplete`, so much of `p:poll` as `p:remoteCommand`.

   Seting  Backing Bean return to Javascript function:

   **Managed Bean**

   ```
   public void teste() {
       // Processamento necessário

       RequestContext context = RequestContext.getInstance();

       // Adiciona as variáveis para o JS (variável args da assinatura)
       context.addCallbackParam("nomeDoAtributo", "valor");
   }
   ```

   Treating the return in JavaScript:

   **JS**

   ```
   function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {
       var nomeDoAtributo = args.nomeDoAtributo;

       // Atualizar UI
       gauge.setValueAnimated(nomeDoAtributo);
   }
   ```